# Event Sourcing for sign up, sign in, sign out

Tags: event-sourcing

A client app allows users to sign up, sign in, and sign out. These operations create user accounts as well as create and delete authentication tokens.

Do even those developers devoted to event sourcing actually use event sourcing for these operations? It seems like these operations need to be synchronous with a central authentication server to check things like username uniqueness and password complexity during sign up and password matching during sign in. Also it is good to see confirmation that sign out was successful for security reasons.

I can see that event sourcing could be used (taking care not to put plain text passwords in the event queue.) It seems like it would make the task of implementing sign up, sign in, and sign out much more onerous on the client app developer. The operations still could not be "offline and sync", could they?

Comment: "Do even those developers devoted to event sourcing actually use event sourcing for these operations?" - you expect that ALL the developers that use event sourcing respond to your question? or there is some master developer that speaks for all of us?

Comment: I don't expect them all to respond. I hope they all do. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do even those developers devoted to event sourcing actually use event sourcing for these operations?

You certainly could -- there's no fundamental reason why you can't use a persistent data structure to maintain your changes, rather than a non-persistent structure.

Which is to say, truth is still written down in a single, central location by the appropriate authority; the difference is that, using event sourcing, the authority doesn't overwrite the previous values.

"Load the current representation from a stream of events" is no less synchronous than "load the current representation from an overwritable store."